# 2-step sign-up page is not working as expected

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a account sign-up in 2 steps (2 forms) .

The first step (the first form) contains just the `username`, `email`, `password` and `confirm password`.

When the first form is validated, I want to make it hidden, and then the second step comes (second form). I'm using php to `include()` forms, but the second `include` doesn't show up.

```
<?php
    include("includes/widgets/register.php");
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["mail"];
        $pass1 = $_POST["pass1"];
        $pass2 = $_POST["pass2"];
         if (empty($username) === false || empty($email) === false || empty($pass1) === false || empty($pass2) === false) {

             include("includes/widgets/registerstp2.php");

             echo '<style type="text/css">
                #step1Account {
                display: none;
                             }';
             echo   '</style>';

             echo $username . ' email :' . $email . ' pass1 :' . $pass1 . ' pass2 :' . $pass2;

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does this portion show up: `echo $username . ' email :' . $email . ' pass1 :' . $pass1 . ' pass2 :' . $pass2;`?

Comment: You can also use `!empty($username)` instead of `empty($username) === false`

Comment: You also may be wanting to make sure all are not empty?? If so, then use `&&` not `||`

Comment: I'd also hash the password before you echo it in plain text in a hidden field.

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do as the style will never be applied. Use jquery with ajax to achieve that.

Comment: @PedroLobito Out of curiosity, why would the style never be applied in this scenario?

Comment: @PedroLobito while I agree `AJAX` is the better route, if this code is in the `head` then the `style` tag would work just fine, no?

Comment: @Rasclatt the only style in the code, pay attention to the code, do you think the style will be applied ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Unless there is something I am missing, provided the form or wrapper has the id named `step1Account` it will work. I have tested this code (with changes like `!empty` and replacing `&&`) and it works fine, hiding the form with `id="step1Account"`. What are you referring to that I am not seeing?

Comment: **" have tested this code"**  how can you test the code with `includes`you don't have ?

Comment: @PedroLobito You are making obscure reference to the fact that there is an issue in the include? If that is what you are referring to, then say it. As posted and with changes, the code will work *provide the include has no errors and is located in the correct location*.

Comment: 1 rst include contain a form . and i want it to be hidden when it's submited .and then  the second include will be displayed . it(s possible to use two page the first one redirect me to the second when i's submited . but i want to make these step in includes files and use it in one page . pliiiiiz help